# DBQuery for date comparison in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

```
DBResultSet *rset = [[[DBDietCharts query] whereWithFormat:@"dbUser = %@ AND startdateString >= 2015-09-25 07:41:00 +0000 ",objDBUserDetails] fetch];
```

but i didn't get any result for dbquery for date comparisons from database using DBQuery

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: Does DBQuery manage comparison with dates as strings? Without any NSDateFormatter?

Comment: i don't know but i have to get the data from database using this DBQuery. Please anyone help